# DotNetZip trouble with coding

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetzip

I am using DotNetZip. When i am archiving file which have english name all normally. but when i archiving file with russian names in result archive with bad names of file. Some peoplese said that string

```
ZipConstants.DefaultCodePage = 866;
```

But it not compile. I also use zip.UseUnicodeAsNecessary properties, and convert my file names to utf8 and utf7.

Comment: sorry I'm a little confused between this two libraries:
http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/
http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/releases/view/27890
in first alll really works like i am want. but i very interested how do this on second. because second library have the good clases what can: add files, folders in archives.

Comment: Don't convert file names to utf8 yourself, leave it up to the library to do it for you.

Comment: The constant you referred to does not exist in DotNetZip.  Also, there's no need to "convert" your filenames from utf-8 to utf-7, or anything else. DotNetZip will do the string encoding for you, in the code page you select. see http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DotNetZipHelp/html/aecbb638-1ecf-807e-b933-5bb1a2a95e81.htm

Comment: Try using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx in .net 4.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To create a unicode zip file in DotNetZip:

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
   zip.UseUnicodeAsNecessary= true;
   zip.AddFile(filename, "directory\\in\\archive");
   zip.Save("archive.zip");
}
```

If you want a particular, specific code page, then you must use something else:

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
   zip.ProvisionalAlternateEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
   zip.AddFile(filename, "directory\\in\\archive");
   zip.Save("archive.zip");
}
```

Check [the documentation](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DotNetZipHelp/frames.htm) for those properties before using them!

Comment: UseUnicodeAsNecessary is obsolete, and use below code is recommended:

zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.Always;
zip.AlternateEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

Answer (score 22):

```
zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.Always;
zip.AlternateEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: Windows Explorer does not support UTF-8 encoded zip files. To read the zip you create, you will have to use a tool or library that supports unicode, such as WinRar, DotNetZip, etc.

Comment: I have successfully opened UTF-8 zip file on my Windows 8.1 machine.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
zip.AddEntry("yourfile.txt", "yourtext", Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
```

encoding type :  [encoding type info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Codest's solution didn't work for me, this one did :)

Comment: Works only if you are providing string content, not byte[].