# vba, how to zip file with special characters?

Tags: excel, vba, zip, compression

When zipping all files in a folder i get an error

```
    '''''Create empty Zip File
    NewZip (FileNameZip)
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    '''''Copy the files to the compressed folder

    oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(FolderName).items ''error here
```

Error:
c:...\Jørgen.doc cannot be compressed because it includes characters that cannot be in a compressed folder, such as ø. You should rename this file or directory.

However if i navigate to the file and manually copy it to the zip folder it works no problem. Is there a way to get round this error in my vba code

Comment: Very interesting Q. +1. I guess it's more of a system level thing than something to do with VBA. But not 100% sure. Would be curious to see what the solution is.

Comment: What are you doing when you are Manually copying?like drag and drop into the zip file?

Comment: yes drag and drop or copy paste

Comment: @hnk - if it were a system problem then i would not be able to do it manually either no?

Comment: I mean, the system might not grant privileges to an application calling it the same way it grants a user operating the GUI. Again, just a guess.

Comment: @user3392351: Not strictly an answer, but I had so many issues fumbling around with the VBA zip file hacks that I switched to a shell call to 7zip.  The VBA way is buggy and I've had lots of issues depending on what machine I was on.  With 7zip, no problems.  I've tried with your filename and it works.  If you're interested here is where you can get the exe (http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) and here's some command line references (http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples).  It's a time investment to change your routines, but 7zip is MUCH stabler.

Answer (score 5):

It's already a standard feature in MacOS, but in Windows 10 you need to to the following:

Type "region" in the Start Menu search box

1. Open the Region and Language Control Panel
2. Click the Administrative tab on the top
3. In "Language for non-Unicode programes" section, click "Change system locale...".
4. Check "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwise language support."
5. Restart Windows and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Use dotnetzip. It supports international (unicode) filenames.

See [here in the answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565414/dotnetzip-trouble-with-coding).