# Invalid filename retrieved from zip file C#

Tags: c#, .net, zip, dotnetzip

Hi I'm trying to read a zip file which contains multiple files. Few of the files inside is named in Arabic.
My file name: (Final تدريب.pdf) becomes (Final óº⌐∩á.pdf) instead. I hope you can guide me.

**Here is my code:**

```
using Ionic.Zip;

                  using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(path))
                    {

                        foreach (var entry in zip.Entries)
                        {
                            string name = entry.FileName;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What zip library you're using here? It doesn't appear to be the System.IO.Compression classes for zip files.

Comment: @John I've tried System.IO.Compression and Ionic.zip
And they both don't work for me.

Comment: Please re-read my comment.

Comment: OK, but what library is the code in your question for? What are you using _now_?

Comment: Is your code above [DotNetZip](https://documentation.help/DotNetZip/554e5329-cb85-7d08-e34b-b6279b5ff744.htm) ?

Comment: @John Yes is DotNetZip

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565414/dotnetzip-trouble-with-coding)

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work with me.

Comment: Does the zip file show the name correctly if you open it in WIndows, or with another zip application? Have you provided the correct encoding to DotNetZip? I've not use DotNetZip but you've definitely got an encoding issue.

Comment: When I decompress it in windows, it shows me the correct file names. 
Yes, I provided utf8 encoding and it showed me invalid filenames for arabic characters.